# Issue with Bash reading file and building string

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'm attempting to read all the lines of a file and concatenate them into a string. After Googling extensively, here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='file.txt'
files=''

while read p; do
    files="$files $p"
done < $filename

echo $files
```

The problem is that it seems the files variable seems to get overwritten each time. Shouldn't it just be appending it?

Example file.txt:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Output is:

```
 test2
```

(Note that I intentially posted this as is - there is a space prior to the word `test2` in the output)

Comment: Can't reproduce...getting `test1 test2 test3`

Comment: Just use `files=$(cat $filename)`.

Comment: @heemayl Hmm. I am on Windows using Git Bash. Posted exactly what I'm running

Comment: @ThomasBPreusser I tried that, it just gave me the last line

Comment: Can you show output of `while IFS= read -r p; do
    declare -p p
done < "$filename"`

Comment: Try to visualize process(es) IDs in- and outside the cycle, something like this: `echo "parent shell=$$"; files=; while read r; do   files="$files $r";   echo "pid=$$; r=$r"; done < "$filename"`

Comment: Could it be that the CR in your Windows text files just hides the rest? It would still be there. You just do not see it on the screen.

Comment: It does look like this is the case. As chepner and strobelight pointed out almost simultaneously, it was the carriage returns causing an issue. Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input file has DOS line endings, and does not end with a newline. This means that the value of files is really `test1\r test2\r`. `test3` is never added because the last call to `read`, which sets `p` to `test3`, has an exit status of 1 resulting from its failure to find a final newline character.

The terminal treats a carriage return as an instruction to move the cursor to the beginning of the line, so everything following a `\r` overwrites whatever was previously written on the line.

The right thing to do is to fix your input file so that it conforms to the POSIX standard for text files: all lines, including the last one, are terminated by a single `\n` character.

Comment: You could also hack the loop to deal with DOS format, with `while IFS=$'\r' read p || [[ -n "$p" ]]; do`. The IFS setting will make it trim trailing carriage return(s), and the `||` clause will continue the loop for the last (not-properly-terminated) line.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your file.txt has carriage returns.

To check this out, change your last line:

> echo $files | cat -v